# Make delete from Database and delete from FileSystem transactional?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have the following method which deletes an image from the file system and its corresponding records from the database.

```
  boolean delete(ImageItem imageItem) {
    boolean success = false
    String imageId = imageItem.id

    ...

    Path outFile = Paths.get(fileUrl)
    if (Files.deleteIfExists(outFile)) {
      log.debug "delete() - file deleted: ${fileUrl}"
      success = true
    }

    try{
      imageItem.delete(flush: true)
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.debug "delete() - Record deleted failed: ${e}"
      success = false
    }

    return success
  }
```

I want to make both delete operations transactional  meaning that either both operations proceed or non.

**Is there a way of doing this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can do it!

```
ImageItem.withTransaction {status ->
   try {
      imageItem.delete(flush: true)
   } catch (Exception e) {
      status.setRollbackOnly()   
      return 
   }

   Path outFile = Paths.get(fileUrl)
   try{
      if (Files.deleteIfExists(outFile)) {
        log.debug "delete() - file deleted: ${fileUrl}"
      } catch (e) {
         status.setRollbackOnly()
      }
}
```

First you try to delete the database record (rolling back if it fails) and then you delete the actual file(s).

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html

Comment: And what happens if the file fails to delete? Does the exception bubble up and roll back the transaction? ;)

Comment: Then you rollback the transaction afterwards - changing the code right now to accommodate this.

Comment: That's the best you can do, but it's not transactional. If the commit fails for whatever reason, the file deletion won't be rollbacked.

Comment: This is not transactional.

Comment: You know what, there are transactional wrappers around file system (xa-disk being one of them) but it's much easier this way.

Comment: @defectus is there a way to integrate the transactional wrapper you mentioned in Grails?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by marking this method with @Transactional annotation. To rollback the transaction you should throw a runtime exception. So by organizing your code and making the file deletion logic in the end of the method you can make sure both of actions will be rollbacked in case of error.

```
@Transactional
 boolean delete(ImageItem imageItem) {
    boolean success = false
    String imageId = imageItem.id

    ...

   try{
      imageItem.delete(flush: true)
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    Path outFile = Paths.get(fileUrl)
    //@TODO:Throw Runtime exception in case of file deletion failure
    if (Files.deleteIfExists(outFile)) {
      log.debug "delete() - file deleted: ${fileUrl}"
      success = true
    }

    return success
  }
```

Comment: Is ``@Transactional`` the same as ``ImageItem.withTransaction{...}``?

Comment: Yes, but the withTransaction allows you to put you transactional code anywhere. It is always best to separate your concerns and put your transactional code in a transactional service. Keep in mind that services are transactional by default.